# disable the native keyboard with javascript when clicking on input field

Tags: javascript, forms, input, keyboard

I need to disable the native keyboard on ios devices when clicking on an input field, I tried to use the "read-only" attribute, however it disables the caret as well and the cursor is not visible anymore. is there any way to fix this issue with javascript? 
I also tried using this.blur() to stop loading the keyboard. but it shows the keyboard for a moment and then disappears.

Comment: ios devices only!?

Comment: any touch device that uses native keyboard would be fine